# Computer (Sometimes) Turns white and freezes for 5 second when I right click

Tags: windows-10, freeze, troubleshooting

Whenever I right click on the home screen of my computer, my cursor displays that dreaded blue circle and eventually turns kind of white. After about 5 or so seconds, the shortcuts I have on my home screen seem to disappear, then 'reload' and everything is completely fine.

This only happens sometimes, and I think it's due to the software that shows the same kind of behavior when I right click on it to delete it.

Any help?

Comment: When this happens, open Reliability History (Control Panel, Security and Maintenance) and tell us what the errors are. One guess is that Windows Explorer has stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was an issue between Visual Studio and Microsoft's OneDrive. Permanently closing the OneDrive fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably caused by some third-party extension to the context menu that
manages to crash Windows. It would usually tend to happen more often with the
first time after the boot that you right-click an item in Explorer.
It might also be dependent upon the file-type of the item.

Try to boot in Safe mode to see if this is happening. If the problem disappears,
then this is indeed the cause of it.

The next step would be to download the free utility
[ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html),
either the installation package or the portable Zip package.

Do this:

- Start ShellExView. The entries with pink background are third-party.
- select all the entries marked with pink, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>
  for adding single or a range to the selection
- Click on the red button on top left corner to disable
- Reboot
- If the issue is resolved then it was definitely caused by one of the disabled
  shell extensions
- Start enabling the disabled extensions one-by-one or in ranges,
  until the issue occurs again, so you have found the troublesome extension
  (and by implication the product that installed it).
  A reboot is required after each change.
- Once this extension is known, you may either uninstall the product, or just leave
  the extension disabled.